# SQL Server: DATEADD bypass dates based on the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have two tables

tbl_date1

```
date_str   |  int_add
12/1/2016  |    5
12/2/2016  |    2
12/4/2016  |    4
```

tbl_date2 (Dates to be bypassed)

```
date_bpass
12/3/2016
12/4/2016
```

Result:

```
date_str   |  int_add | final_date
12/1/2016  |    5     |  12/8/2016
12/2/2016  |    2     |  12/6/2016
12/4/2016  |    4     |  12/8/2016
```

I want the query to return the final_date column value wherein the final_date is the DATEADD of the date_str and int_add but should not include
the dates present in tbl_date2.

Thank You

Comment: Adding 5 days to `12/1/2016`  will give `12/6/2016` which is not a bypass date so, How you got `12/8/2016` final_date in first row ?

Comment: Are your column 'int_add' ('5,2,4')  were default values?

Comment: @Prdp 2 days will be added in the original 5 days since 12/3/2016 and 12/4/2016 will not be included in the count

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen the values vary based on the user input

Comment: how did you get the final_date = 12/08/2016? when the date_str = 12/1/2016 + 5? it should be 12/6/2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
SELECT date_str,
       int_add,
       Dateadd(dd, int_add + add_count, date_str)
FROM   tbl_date1 a
       OUTER apply (SELECT Count(1)
                    FROM   tbl_date2 b
                    WHERE  b.date_bpass BETWEEN Dateadd(dd, 1, a.date_str) AND Dateadd(dd, a.int_add, a.date_str)) cs (add_count)
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/FXLATN64551)

Comment: Thanks! i will try to test this :) God Bless

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! just what i needed

Comment: What if the final_date falls on the bypassed date sir?

Comment: @RyanAbarquez - Ask a new question with valid sample data. It should cover the scenario you are saying and expected result